# Folgen mit haben/sein

Tags: verb-usage

Ich mache gerade Übungsgrammatik für die Oberstufe und ehrlich gesagt, für mich stimmt etwas nicht.

Im Lösungsschlüssel steht:

> Die Besucher sind den Anweisungen der Platzanweiser gefolgt.

Ich würde lieber „haben“ gebrauchen, was meint ihr?

Comment: Was spricht denn dafür, dass nur eines richtig sein kann?

Answer (score 5):

*Haben gefolgt* hat den Sinn von [jemandem gehorchen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/folgen#2).

Man könnte also sagen,

> Die Besucher haben dem Platzanweiser gefolgt.

So wie das Kinder der Mutter folgt.

In dem Satz

> Die Besucher sind den Anweisungen der Platzanweiser gefolgt.

geht es aber nicht darum, dem Platzanweiser zu gehorchen, sondern seinen Anweisungen zu folgen, so wie man einer Fährte oder einer Beschreibung folgt. Ich halte daher *sind gefolgt* im Sinne von *einen vorgegebenen Weg gehen* für richtig.

Anders wäre es bei der Formulierung

> Die Besucher haben den Anweisungen der Platzanweiser Folge geleistet.

Da ist das Verb aber *leisten* und nicht *folgen*.

Comment: Habe +1 gegeben, weil ich die gemachte Unterscheidung für wichtig halte. Aber mein Sprachgefühl läßt bei *folgen* im Sinne von *gehorchen* mit *haben* im Perfekt kein Dativobjekt zu: *Er hat immer gefolgt* ist in Ordnung, *er hat uns immer gefolgt* nicht.

Comment: @DavidVogt Beispiel [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/folgen#2): das Kind hat seiner Mutter, seinem Lehrer immer gefolgt

Answer (score 1):

Du hast recht. [Laut Duden gilt](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/folgen):

> er ist mir gefolgt (nachgekommen); er hat mir gefolgt (Gehorsam geleistet);

Da den Platzanweisern Gehorsam geleistet wird, muss es heißen

> Die Besucher **haben** den Anweisungen der Platzanweiser gefolgt.

Comment: Es wird nicht den Anweisungen Gehorsam geleistet, sondern dem Platzanweiser. Folgen bezieht sich im Originalsatz aber nicht auf den Platzanweiser sondern dessen Anweisungen.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: Man kann auch Anweisungen nachkommen und einem Befehl Gehorsam leisten.

Comment: @userunknown Nein, kann man nicht. [Gehorsam](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gehorsam) ist die Unterordnung unter den Willen einer Autorität. Man kann dem Befehlenden Gehorsam leisten aber nicht dem Befehl.

Comment: @Olafant: Deine Quelle listet "Gehorsam gegen das Gesetz". Klassisches Eigentor, oder?

Comment: @userunknown Inwiefern ist das ein Eigentor? *Gehorsam gegen das Gesetz sein* ist wohl kaum dasselbe wie *dem Gesetz Gehorsam leisten*. Wenn ich gehorsam gegen das Gesetz bin, leiste ich dem Gesetzgeber Gehorsam.

Comment: @Olafant: Nein, eben nicht. Der Executive gegenüber kannst Du Gehorsam sein, also einem spezifischen Zollbeamten oder Polizisten z.B., aber dem Gesetzgeber gegenüber nicht - dem bist Du auch nicht zum Gehorsam verpflichtet, sondern nur dem Gesetz selbst.

Comment: @userunknown Wenn ich dem Gesetz folge, folge ich dem Willen des Gesetzgebers, nicht dem des Polizisten.

Comment: @Olafant: Das war nicht die Alternative, die ich aufgemacht habe. Dem Gesetz folgen und dem Willen des Gesetzgebers ist nicht immer das gleiche - bekannt vom Buchstaben des Gesetzes, dem man folgt. Auslegung d. Gesetzes nach Buchstaben, nach Intention oder nach etablierter Rechtsprechung sind explizites Thema bei Juristen. Wie dem auch sei: Anweisungen können auch schriftlich aushängen, auch dann kann man sagen, man habe den Anweisungen Gehorsam geleistet, und es wird auch gesagt.

Comment: Wofür gab's denn ein Downvote?